# What is best practice with TS and React types when it comes to events?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events

I'm trying to write React with TS and I dont want to believe that I have to pass these long types `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>` to the component to make it work.
What is the best practice to use this? Where do I find all possible types(not counting string, number and such) for events? Thank you.

My Component:

```
  export function Button({action, description}:{action: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>, description: string}) {

  return(
    <button onClick={action}>{description}</button>
  )

}
```